# Polymer lit-element in polymer 1 app...possible?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-elements, lit-element

New to Polymer BTW. I have polymer 1 app running. Wondering if I can use Polymer lit-elements in Polymer 1?

Trying to achieve: Ask is to embed another module which is written in JavaScript by another team in my company to my polymer1 app. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Alot of changes have been made since the below answer was given. It may be possible now. Not sure.

No, as far as mixing with other Polymer library iterations, lit-element is stand alone and a upgrade from Polymer 3.

From https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-05-02-roadmap-faq

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In summary:
No

Basically it is impossible.
You should consider upgrading to polymer 3 to use lit element

Polymer 1 is not even used in Classes, so it is practically impossible and polymer 1 is falling into disuse so the polymer team do not think it plans to support this new feature.